# Proguard keep option to handle OSGi declarative service

Tags: osgi, proguard, osgi-bundle

What is the keep option to use for OSGi declarative service to obfuscate with Proguard

Referring to the example below, I need to keep the DS relevant functions without Proguard removes it, because it cant find the reference

```
@Component
public class RandomApp {

    private RandomGenApi randomGenApi;

    @Reference
    public void setRandomGenService(RandomGenApi randomGenApi) {
        this.randomGenApi = randomGenApi;
    }
      
    
    @Activate
    void startRandomApp() {
        System.out.println("Startig RandomApp...");          

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could achieve this by defining the OSGi services as the entry points.
Here is the keep options to be defined

```
#Keep annotations.
-keepattributes *Annotation*

#Keep all Component classes
-keep @org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Component class *

#Kepp all Component classes member functions with OSGi specific annotations
-keepclassmembers @org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Component class * {
   #Keep all methods with annotatios Reference.
   @org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Reference *;
   #Keep all methods with annotatios Activate.
   @org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Activate *;   
}
```